# Is it possible to trigger windows 10 to turn off while connected to WSL via SSH?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, remote-desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use my remote Windows 10 PC WSL system as development server, connecting to it using ssh.

The little inconvenient I have is that after I am done with my work I have to connect to the machine using Remote Desktop or Teamviewer to manually turn off the PC.

Is there a way to shutdown the PC from WSL ?

Extra info:

- I turn the PC on using Wake-on-lan, so no active user session exist on windows.
- `shutdown.exe` does not work

Comment: Maybe run `shutdown -s -f` in WSL?

Comment: [Try what is described here](https://lifehacker.com/shut-down-your-windows-pc-remotely-from-linux-5275652) but as it mentions you can get problems because of the firewall. [Create Inbound Rules to Support RPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-inbound-rules-to-support-rpc). Another alternative is to have a script start on boot checking for a file that is modified within x amount of time, then you just `touch` that file from WSL and it triggers a shutdown from the script running on the dev server.